# Is it possible to know, when running jetty server started?

Tags: jetty, jetty-9, jetty-8

I would like to know when my jetty server started.
is there any command/any other way, that can show, when the running jetty server started?

Answer (score 0):

if you are start jetty from command line then `sudo service jetty start` will give you the starting time as well it will start the server or you can use `sudo service jetty check` to get the starting time of jetty server

Comment: Thanks for writing.
Getting below error. Any Idea?
**sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo**

Comment: try this https://www.shell-tips.com/2014/09/08/sudo-sorry-you-must-have-a-tty-to-run-sudo/